# What kind of Typewriter font is that

Tags: fonts

I downloaded this [kindle ebook](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/28076) from Gutenberg and opened it on my Kindle, and there is this amazing typeface, which I have a hard time to recognize.

[image: Screenshot from Kindle]

I passed this image through all possible font search engines. I found many "typewriter" type of fonts, but nothing that will be exactly "clean" as this one....

Maybe someone of you know what kind of typeface is that?

Comment: Your link goes to a list of several ebooks. If you did download the "Kindle with images" version, you got a .mobi file. Now your Kindle will display one of its inbuilt fonts, at least my Kindle does. So please provide more information on your own Kindle: is it a real divice or a virtual Kindle? What generation? On my Kindle the Typefaces look different.

Comment: How did you get that screenshot please? I have never seen a way to do that on a Kindle?

Comment: Screenshot from Kindle is taken by pressing two opposite corners at the same time. Then connect Kindle via USB to your laptop and get screenshots from the root folder

Comment: I used Kindle Paperwhite (bought it about 3 years ago). When I open Mobi on Calibre (windows version ) then typeface is also different...